# Multer - Error with stream.pipeline() : chunk argument not valid

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I have a problem with stream.pipeline()

```
await pipeline(
    req.file.buffer,
    fs.createWriteStream(
        `${__dirname}/../client/public/uploads/profil/${fileName}`
    )
)
```

When i do this, I have an error : `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type number (255)`

req.file :

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'test.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 00 16 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 05 03 04 04 04 03 05 04 04 04 05 05 05 06 07 0c 08 07 07 ... 195029 more bytes>,
  size: 195079
}
```

So please if you can help me! Sorry for my english, I don't have a good english..

Comment: Do u find something ?